# 3D Convolution function C++ (no libraries or FFT)

Tags: c++, image-processing, filtering

I've been following a paper which at some stage mentions 'calculating the gradient over a 5x5 neighbourhood'. However, the supplementary code simply uses gradient(I, 2, 2). As far as I'm aware that just makes the step size 2 but still computes the gradient using central finite difference between 2 adjacent points (for each direction) but divides by 2 instead (please tell me if I'm wrong here).

So, instead I assume perhaps that computing the gradient via sobel for 5x5 makes more sense.

However, I'm doing this in 3D so I have been trying to write a 3D convolution function (note: I don't want to use libraries for this or the FFT method. Speed isn't a problem here).

```
typedef boost::multi_array<float, 3> array_type;
typedef array_type::index index;


float convolve3D(const array_type& input, int x, int y, int z, int iWidth, int iHeight, int iDepth, const array_type& kernel, int kernelSize)
{

    auto isOutsidePixel = [&](int xPos, int yPos, int zPos)->int
    {
        if(xPos >= 0 && xPos < iWidth && yPos >= 0 && yPos < iHeight && zPos >= 0 && zPos < iDepth)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    };

    float result = 0.0f;
    int xPos, yPos, zPos;

    int filterSize = 3;

    for(int k = 0; k < kernelSize; k++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < kernelSize; j++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < kernelSize; i++)
            {
                xPos = x + i-(kernelSize/2);
                yPos = y + j-(kernelSize/2);
                zPos = z + k-(kernelSize/2);


                if(isOutsidePixel(xPos, yPos, zPos) == false)
                {
                    result += kernel[i][j][k] * input[xPos][yPos][zPos];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I then feed this function some test data to test on just the x kerenel to get the x component:

```
x_kernel[0][0][0] = -1.0f;  x_kernel[1][0][0] =  0.0f;  x_kernel[2][0][0] =  1.0f;
x_kernel[0][1][0] = -2.0f;  x_kernel[1][2][0] =  0.0f;  x_kernel[2][3][0] =  2.0f;
x_kernel[0][2][0] = -1.0f;  x_kernel[1][2][0] =  0.0f;  x_kernel[2][2][0] =  1.0f;

x_kernel[0][0][1] = -2.0f;  x_kernel[1][0][1] = 0.0f;   x_kernel[2][0][1] = 2.0f;
x_kernel[0][4][1] = -4.0f;  x_kernel[1][5][1] = 0.0f;   x_kernel[2][6][1] = 4.0f;
x_kernel[0][2][1] = -2.0f;  x_kernel[1][2][1] = 0.0f;   x_kernel[2][2][1] = 2.0f;

x_kernel[0][0][2] = -1.0f; x_kernel[1][0][2] = 0.0f;  x_kernel[2][0][2] = 1.0f;
x_kernel[0][7][2] = -2.0f; x_kernel[1][8][2] = 0.0f;  x_kernel[2][9][2] = 2.0f;
x_kernel[0][2][2] = -1.0f; x_kernel[1][2][2] = 0.0f;  x_kernel[2][2][2] = 1.0f;
```

with my image being

```
I[0][0][0] = 5;   I[0][10][0] = 30;  I[0][2][0] = 20;
I[1][0][0] = 10;  I[1][11][0] = 10;  I[1][2][0] = 5;
I[2][0][0] = 20;  I[2][12][0] = 5;      I[2][2][0] = 100;

I[0][0][1] = 500;  intensityArray2[0][13][1] = 50; intensityArray2[0][2][1] = 70;
I[1][0][1] = 200;  intensityArray2[1][14][1] = 5;  intensityArray2[1][2][1] = 75;
I[2][0][1] = 100;  intensityArray2[2][15][1] = 10; intensityArray2[2][2][1] = 45;

I[0][0][2] = 400; I[0][16][2] = 90;  I[0][2][2] = 30;
I[1][0][2] = 50;  I[1][17][2] = 100; I[1][2][2] = 45;
I[2][0][2] = 20;  I[2][18][2] = 90;  I[2][2][2] = 60;
```

I get the following result:

```
465 , -830 , -465 ,
355 , -415 , -355 ,
195 , 180 , -195 ,


1040 , -2435 , -1040 ,
900 , -1315 , -900 ,
520 , 15 , -520 ,


805 , -2360 , -805 ,
875 , -1205 , -875 ,
535 , 30 , -535 ,
```

In MATLAB I then replicate the same kernel and image.

```
k(:,:,1) = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1];
k(:,:, 2) = [-2 0 2; -4 0 4 ; -2 0 2];
k(:,:,3) = [-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1];

I(:,:,1) = [5 30 20; 10 10 5; 20 5 100];
I(:, :, 2) = [500 50 70; 200 5 75; 100 10 45];
I(:,:,3) = [400 90 30; 50 100 45; 20, 90, 60];

convn(I,k)
```

and get the following result.

```
ans(:,:,1) =

    -5   -30   -15    30    20
   -20   -70   -25    70    45
   -45   -55   -85    55   130
   -50   -20  -155    20   205
   -20    -5   -80     5   100

ans(:,:,2) =

   -510   -110    400    110    110
   -1240   -245    935    245    305
  -1090   -180    565    180    525
   -500    -65    -75     65    575
   -140    -20   -105     20    245

ans(:,:,3) =

  -1405   -220   1215    220    190
  -3270   -560   2690    560    580
  -2565   -575   1725    575    840
   -940   -350    240    350    700
   -240   -115    -10    115    250

ans(:,:,4) =

  -1300   -230   1170    230    130
  -2900   -665   2475    665    425
  -2040   -830   1415    830    625
   -580   -585     85    585    495
   -140   -190    -25    190    165

ans(:,:,5) =

  -400   -90   370    90    30
  -850  -280   745   280   105
  -520  -380   340   380   180
   -90  -280   -75   280   165
   -20   -90   -40    90    60
```

The central pixels (I'm not concerned about the added extra image size bits) don't seem to be matching up. This method worked for 2D and I just expanded it to 3D. Is there anything immediately obvious that I've done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Please don't paste images of text, paste the text directly.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the question now.